# MVC DropDownList Displays System.web.mvc.SelectListItem

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I made a drop down list using `@Html.DropDownList()`
But instead of displaying my list items, it displays `System.web.mvc,selectlist item`

Here's the code:

```
@{
List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Text = "Department",
    Value = "dep"
});
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Text = "Designation",
    Value = "des",
    Selected = true
});
```

}

### Index

```
@Html.DropDownList("Filter",
                new SelectList(listItems.ToList()),
                "Filter By:",
                new { @class = "form-control" })
```

[image]

Comment: try removing .ToList

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/basics-of-aspnet-mvc-dropdowns-J7)

Comment: Its just `@Html.DropDownList("Filter", listItems, "..", new { ... })`